# IE8 @font-face not working while having correct code

Tags: fonts, internet-explorer-8, font-face, webfonts

I'm trying to get @font-face to work for IE 8 but it won't work. I allready have the correct code. What else can possibly be wrong?

```
@font-face {
font-family: "HelveticaNeueCn";
src: url("/font/HelveticaNeueLTCom-Cn.eot");
src: url("/font/HelveticaNeueLTCom-Cn.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
     url("/font/HelveticaNeueLTCom-Cn.woff") format("woff"), 
     url("/font/HelveticaNeueLTCom-Cn.ttf") format("truetype"), 
     url("/font/HelveticaNeueLTCom-Cn.svg") format("svg");
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Code looks right, do you have a link?